# How to change \chapterautorefname with cleanthesis template?

Tags: hyperref, autoref, cleanthesis

I tried to change the `\chapterautorefname` as used by `\autoref{}` command but without success. The hint that normally did this job was

```
 \addto\extrasenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
  }
```

but no luck when adding this block to the preamble of a cleanthesis document. Any ideas?

Thanks! 
Max

EDIT:
as suggested in the comments, I try to provide a code example:

```
% **************************************************
% Document Class Definition
% **************************************************
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,               % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,           % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,              % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,           % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,     % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                   % font size
    headings=normal,        % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,     % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,           % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,           % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,    % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,            % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%


\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}

% **************************************************
% Load and Configure Packages
% **************************************************
\usepackage[english]{babel} % babel system, adjust the language of the content
\PassOptionsToPackage{% setup clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    sansserif=false,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    bibsys=biber,%
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=alphabetic,%
    wrapfooter=false,%
}{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{cleanthesis}

\hypersetup{% setup the hyperref-package options
    plainpages=false,           %   -
    colorlinks=false,           %   - colorize links?
    pdfborder={0 0 0},          %   -
    breaklinks=true,            %   - allow line break inside links
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     %
    bookmarksopen=true          %
}

\addto\extrasenglish{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}%
    \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}%
    \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Section}%
}

% **************************************************
% Document CONTENT
% **************************************************
\begin{document}

\chapter{MyFirstChapter}
\label{chap:first}



\chapter{MySecondChapter}
\label{chap:second}
As introduced in \autoref{chap:first}...

% --------------------------
% Body matter
% --------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}          % arabic page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1}            % set page counter
\pagestyle{maincontentstyle}    % fancy header and footer


% --------------------------
% Back matter
% --------------------------
{%
\setstretch{1.1}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\printbibliography[nottype=online]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Webpages},type=online,prefixnumbers={@}]
}

\clearpage
\newpage
\mbox{}

% **************************************************
% End of Document CONTENT
% **************************************************
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments.

Comment: but then I need to include the whole template as well... so there is no simple minimal working example.

The code for cleanthesis can be found here: https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis

Comment: `cleanthesis` is on TL, MikTeX as well... of course your 'MWE' isn't compilable since there's is an `\input` statement.

Comment: Blame `cleanthesis` ;-) Apparently, it screws up the counter/hyperref system by putting wrong labels into `.aux` file, such that `\chapter` writes `section` as label information to the `.aux` file. `cleanthesis` is 'inspired' by `classicthesis` (as the author proudly states in the doc) ... and this says enough ;-)

Comment: Providing a template is something that should be done by experienced users only, as it is a tricky task. An experienced user won't provide a template (in the meaning of cleanthesis), because the experienced user understands that a template is not even needed. So all templates out there will be created by inexperienced users for other inexperienced users. A situation that is bound to fail.

Comment: `titlesec` and KOMA-script are incompatible. `hyperref` is a sensile package which should be loaded last, but is one of the very first loaded by this template.

Comment: Try the development version of the template. It doesn't use `titlesec`, nor `\phantomsection`.